# I am learning to create AWS Lambdas. I want to create a "chain": S3 -> 4 Chained Lambda()'s -> RDS. I can't get the first lambda to call the second

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless

I really tried everything. Surprisingly google has not many answers when it comes to this.

When a certain .csv file is uploaded to a S3 bucket I want to parse it and place the data into a RDS database.

My goal is to learn the lambda serverless technology, this is essentially an exercise. Thus, I over-engineered the hell out of it.

Here is how it goes:

1. S3 Trigger when the .csv is uploaded -> call lambda (this part fully works)
2. `AAA_Thomas_DailyOverframeS3CsvToAnalytics_DownloadCsv` downloads the csv from S3 and finishes with essentially the plaintext of the file. It is then supposed to pass it to the next lambda. The way I am trying to do this is by putting the second lambda as destination. The function works, but the second lambda is never called and I don't know why.
3. `AAA_Thomas_DailyOverframeS3CsvToAnalytics_ParseCsv` gets the plaintext as input and returns a javascript object with the parsed data.
4. `AAA_Thomas_DailyOverframeS3CsvToAnalytics_DecryptRDSPass` only connects to KMS, gets the encrcypted RDS password, and passes it along with the data it received as input to the last lambda.
5. `AAA_Thomas_DailyOverframeS3CsvToAnalytics_PutDataInRds` then finally puts the data in RDS.

I created a custom VPC with custom subnets, route tables, gateways, peering connections, etc. I don't know if this is relevant but function `2.` only has access to the s3 endpoint, `3.` does not have any internet access whatsoever, `4.` is the only one that has normal internet access (it's the only way to connect to KSM), and `5.` only has access to the peered VPC which hosts the RDS.

---

This is the code of the first lambda:

```
// dependencies
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const util = require('util');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
let region = process.env;


exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) =>
{
    var checkDates = process.env.CheckDates == "false" ? false : true;
    var ret = [];
    var checkFileDate = function(actualFileName)
    {
        if (!checkDates)
            return true;
            
        var d = new Date();
        var expectedFileName = 'Overframe_-_Analytics_by_Day_Device_' + d.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + (d.getUTCMonth().toString().length == 1 ? "0" + d.getUTCMonth() : d.getUTCMonth()) + '-' + (d.getUTCDate().toString().length == 1 ? "0" + d.getUTCDate() : d.getUTCDate());

        return expectedFileName == actualFileName.substr(0, expectedFileName.length);
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < event.Records.length; ++i)
    {
        var record = event.Records[i];
        
        try {
            if (record.s3.bucket.name != process.env.S3BucketName)
            {
                console.error('Unexpected notification, unknown bucket: ' + record.s3.bucket.name);
                continue;
            }
            
            if (!checkFileDate(record.s3.object.key))
            {
                console.error('Unexpected file, or date is not today\'s: ' + record.s3.object.key);
                continue;
            }

            const params = {
                Bucket: record.s3.bucket.name,
                Key: record.s3.object.key
            };
            var csvFile = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
            var allText = csvFile.Body.toString('utf-8');
            
            console.log('Loaded data:', {Bucket: params.Bucket, Filename: params.Key, Text: allText});
            
            ret.push(allText);
    
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Couldn't download CSV from S3", error);
            return { statusCode: 500, body: error };
        }  
    }
    
    // I've been randomly trying different ways to return the data, none works. The data itself is correct , I checked with console.log()
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: { "Records": ret }
    };
    
    return ret;
};
```

---

While this shows how the lambda was set up, especially its destination:

[image: Screenshot of AWS Lambda web page]

I haven't posted on Stackoverflow in 7 years. That's how desperate I am. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you looked in CloudWatch Logs to see if any error messages are posted? Also, are you testing the function by creating an object in S3, or by clicking the Test button? (Destinations do not trigger via the Test button.)

Comment: @john cloudwatch has a strange issue where when I open it from the lambda page link it says the group log does not exist; if I try to create it I get an error saying that aws/lambda/* group names are reserved for lambdas. I was using the Test button. That’s almost certainly the issue. I was convinced it would trigger the destination too, otherwise it would be quite confusing (and indeed here we are). Thank you so much.

Comment: check the lambda permission if it able to write log plus you can also view recent logs from the monitoring section.

Comment: Make sure that the IAM Role associated with the Lambda function has the `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` policy assigned, which includes permissions to write to CloudWatch Logs.

Comment: @John is my return function correct? Does it matter what I return?

Comment: Permission policies are okay, it has execute permissions and cloudwatch logs permissions. I even gave it * on cloudwatch logs, as an attempt to resolve the issue, but it didn’t help.

Comment: It is almost certainly the “Test” button as I used it exclusively to try to get the lambdas to chain. The real trigger never hit

Comment: Destinations require async invocation, which will not work via the Test button. You can try testing it by creating an S3 object, then seeing if it works. Alternatively, just call `invoke()` to trigger another Lambda function. (Destinations are quite new, introduced about 6 months ago.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than getting each Lambda to call the next one take a look at AWS managed service for state machines, [step functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) which can handle this workflow for you.

By providing [input and outputs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-input-output-filtering.html) you can pass output to the next function, with retry logic built into it.

If you haven't much experience AWS has a [tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/create-a-serverless-workflow-step-functions-lambda/) on setting up a step function through chaining Lambdas.

By using this you also will not need to account for configuration issues such as Lambda timeouts. In addition it allows your code to be more modular which improves testing the individual functionality, whilst also isolating issues.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will definitely check it out and give it a try because as I said I was more interested in some “generic learning” than to get the csv in the database. I have a lot of AWS experience but none in lambdas and related technologies. I mainly deal with ec2, s3 and vpc’s. Which is why the vpc set up for this was utterly insane 

Comment: No problem, I believe its ideal for what you're looking for as you can have each Lambda be independently managed. Serverless is awesome, I hope you enjoy :)

Comment: I am still looking into step functions, in particular at the moment I am struggling with async callbacks from Node.js lambdas, but state machines (step functions) are definitely the way to go, so I accepted your answer!

Answer (score 1):

The execution roles of all Lambda functions, whose destinations include other Lambda functions, must have the `lambda:InvokeFunction` IAM permission in one of their attached IAM policies.

Here's a snippet from [Lambda documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html?icmpid=docs_lambda_help#invocation-async-destinations):

> To send events to a destination, your function needs additional permissions. Add a policy with the required permissions to your function's execution role. Each destination service requires a different permission, as follows:
>
> - Amazon SQS – sqs:SendMessage
> - Amazon SNS – sns:Publish
> - Lambda – lambda:InvokeFunction
> - EventBridge – events:PutEvents

Comment: This wasn’t the problem in my case as I made sure they were correct according to the documentation (they initially weren’t but I realized it early). Thank you though for posting this, I’m sure it will be helpful to users coming from google for years to come